# Django test DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am trying to test revoke function in the view:

```
@login_required
def revoke(request, id):
    """
    Delete access token
    """
    obj = Hiren.objects.get(pk=id)
    obj.delete()
    return redirect('/hiren')
```

Here is my test code that throws an error:

```
class TestRevokeView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='admin', password='admin', email='admin@admin.lol')
        item = Hiren()
        item.access_token = "bla bla"
        item.authorized = True
        item.save()

    def test_logged_in_user_can_delete_object(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='admin')
        count = Hiren.objects.all().count()
        self.assertEqual(count, 1)
        response = self.client.get('/revoke/1/', follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/hiren/')
```

Here is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".....tests.py", line 109, in test_logged_in_user_can_delete_object
    response = self.client.get('/revoke/1/', follow=True)
 ....................
  self.model._meta.object_name
github.models.DoesNotExist: Hiren matching query does not exist.
```

So my question is what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure that `Hiren` instance that you created on `setUp` method, has `ID` equal to `1`

To avoid that, set `Hiren` id instance a class variable and then use it on your test method.

```
class TestRevokeView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='admin', password='admin', email='admin@admin.lol')
        item = Hiren()
        item.access_token = "bla bla"
        item.authorized = True
        item.save()
        self.HIREN_ID = item.id

    def test_logged_in_user_can_delete_object(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='admin')
        count = Hiren.objects.all().count()
        self.assertEqual(count, 1)
        response = self.client.get('/revoke/%s/' % self.HIREN_ID), follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/hiren/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Probabily, the `pk` of `Hiren` item is not 1.

```
class TestRevokeView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='admin', password='admin', email='admin@admin.lol')
        self.item = Hiren()
        self.item.access_token = "bla bla"
        self.item.authorized = True
        self.item.save()

    def test_logged_in_user_can_delete_object(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='admin')
        count = Hiren.objects.all().count()
        self.assertEqual(count, 1)
        response = self.client.get('/revoke/{0}/'.format(self.item.pk), follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/hiren/')
```